# What is the current frequency of my processor (CPU-Z equivalent)?

Tags: software-recommendation, cpu, cpufreq

Is there a ubuntu program like CPU-Z which will show me the actual frequency of my processor?

I do a fair amount of scientific computing which leads to me running my programs for up to 10 hrs. To alleviate this problem a little I overclock my CPU. However I can't see what the actual clock of my processor from within ubuntu which means I either have to restart and look at the bios or load into windows. If there was an applet or command line command to find out this information it would be very helpful.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file `/proc/cpuinfo` contains information about the cpu(s) on your system. To just get the clock rate, you could run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"`.

Comment: this still gives the value based on my cpu's default clock and not the actual speed. As in, my processor is stock 2.8 GHz, I am running it at 3.2 GHz. running that command returns a value of "2800.000"

Comment: Well then your cpu is running at 2.8 ghz. Maybe the cpufreq daemon is overriding your bios overclock.

Comment: What do you get from the file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies` ? If the overclocked speed is not listed, you should try disabling speedstep when you overclock.

Comment: that shows the same set of frequencies, rubbish. I'm using an AMD chip, so it looks like have got more hunting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can use **CPU-G**,
CPU-G is an application that shows useful information about your hardware which have 'similar' appearence with CPU-Z on windows; see [here](http://goo.gl/0ozIC)

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called " Hardinfo" . It is there in the repository. It will give you the detaiiled hardware indformation about your system. If you are using the old gnome-panels then there is also the " cpu frequency monitoring applet" which will show your current cpu status.

Comment: I really like that program you suggested but I have the same problem as I commented on the other post

Answer (score 2):

Try [**i7z**](http://code.google.com/p/i7z/) if you are using an Intel i3, i5, or i7 CPU.  It shows the actual current CPU frequency, even if you have overclocked it using the BIOS. To see the overclocked speed you'll have to run a job that pushes at least one core, or you'll only see a much lower idle frequency in i7z.

(This answer is almost identical to an answer I gave in [CPU Frequency is off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189208) , but it seems you're interested in the same thing.  Please let me know if this isn't the right way to answer 2 similar questions.)