# CPU Frequency is off

Tags: cpu, frequency

I'm working on overclocking my rig right now, but I need to know the cpu frequency from within Ubuntu. I've figured out that I have to run a stress test while preforming the following commands to get a "accurate" reading, but they still only record stock speed. I've tried `sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo` but that shows my CPU cores running at 800MHz. I've looked in `System Information` but both report my cores running at 2900.00MHz, when the BIOS reports my poor overclocking skills coming in at roughly 3100.00MHz.

After a reboot and overclocking my CPU another 200MHz, both tools now report 3200.0MHz when my BIOS says its just above 3400.00MHz. The tools don't report the stock speed, but I doubt 
they're reporting the real speed, they're about 200MHz low.

What am I doing wrong, why are these tools only reporting my stock settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally, you can see the available CPU frequencies using:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

..the maximum frequencies using:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

and the current CPU frequencies using:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

Comment: I'll look into this when I get the computer back up online.

Answer (score 1):

Try i7z http://code.google.com/p/i7z/ if you are using an Intel i3, i5, or i7 CPU.  It shows the actual current CPU frequency, even if you have overclocked it using the BIOS.

As you mention in your question, to see the overclocked speed you'll have to run a job that pushes at least one core, or you'll only see a much lower idle frequency in i7z.

Answer (score 0):

Looking under BIOS settings, I disabled all CPU "extras", and I was rewarded with the right frequency. I then enabled everything one by one until I found the culprit - AMD PowerNow feature. Disabling it fixed my frequency issue.