# Is there a cpu frequency monitor on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: system-monitor

So I was wondering if there Is a ,,system monitor" program  that measures cpu frequency on ubuntu ??? like windows 8 has in ,,task manager" or ,,cpu-z"

---

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36631/what-is-the-current-frequency-of-my-processor-cpu-z-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is already  one installed it is called **System Monitor** and can be found in the dash by hitting the "Windows"(called Super) key and then you can start typing the name and clicking the icon to open it.  If you are going to be using it frequently you can then right click the icon in the launcher and selecting "Lock to Launcher" it will then stay in the launcher and you can click the icon to open it.  Here is a screenshot....

[image]
 as you can see it is a lot like the Windows task manager and can show you what Processes are running as well and you can kill a process with a right click as well as get file system info(how much free space ect) and general system info(kernel number, computer name ect)

There is a indicator app that allows you to see/control the speed in Ghz of the processor but I don't know anything about it is called `indicator-cpufreq` and can be found in the Software Center or [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but I am looking for a system monitor that shows cpu frequency/GHz

Comment: @Levan OK, sorry I misunderstood the question but I have edited it to include a app indicator that you can install that should do what you need

Comment: Thank you again for the answer but i wanted to monitor my cpu freq when I monitor cpu freq on windows 8 it jumps up and down all the time and it never reaches cpu limit so I wanted to see how linux/ubuntu handles stuff again thank you